# Tracking expiration date in SP2010 workflow

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I have a document library with a field titled "Status" containing either the values "Waiting" or "Complete", as well as a "Due date" column.

I am designing an SP2010 workflow which will send e-mails when either the list item's status is set to "Complete", or "Due date" has been reached.

To deal with this logic I am using a ConditionedActivity group in such a manner as below.

```
CAG: Until isComplete=true || isExpired=true
    Sequence1 - run once
    While isComplete=false
            OnWorkFlowItemChanged: set isComplete
Sequence2 - run while isComplete=false
        IfElseActivity
            if "Due date" has been reached
        isExpired=true
    else
        Delay for x amount of time
```

Never mind the fact that the DelayActivity seems to have a mind of its own when it comes to how long it chooses to delay, but it takes a long time (from instantly to > 10 minutes in worst case) for the OnWorkFlowItemChanged activity to run after I've made an update to the list.

What can be the cause of this? I would have thought initially that the Delay activity just blocks the first sequence, but I see in the logs that the OnWorkFlowItemChanged event will be raised while the Delay activity is sleeping the second sequence.

Is this even the way to do this? Can I solve this issue somehow, or are there other alternatives on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In a production environment workflow activities can que for a period of time, especially if you have a heavy load of workflow activities to be processed. Check the workflow status page and make sure your workflow activity has not been put in a que for processing.  Should be a red text error message.